# Is my jSON well written?

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data

is my jSON well written ? i just have boxes with their detail and i want to populate a core data entity afterwards. (btw, i need a easy tutorial to set my datas in coredata, do you have? cimgf's tutorial is too complicated or i just don't understand them :/

```
{
    "boxes": {
    "boxesDetail": [
        {
            "codeArticle": "WPCDE01C412L",
            "nameBox": "boxName",
            "texteMarketing": "boxTextMarketing",
            "descriptionBox": "boxDescritpion",
            "nbActivities": 1650,
            "kindBox": "boxKind",
            "typeBox": "boxType",
            "priceBox": 20,
            "dlu": 2014,
            "note": 3
        },
        {
            "codeArticle": "BOOYAKA!!",
            "nameBox": "boxNameName",
            "texteMarketing": "boxTextMarketing",
            "descriptionBox": "boxDescritpion",
            "nbActivities": 1650,
            "kindBox": "boxKind",
            "typeBox": "boxType",
            "priceBox": 39,
            "dlu": 2014,
            "note": 3
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: JSONLint http://jsonlint.com/ says it's valid JSON.

Comment: There's not enough to say.  You have a lot of repeated data, but I don't know if it's always repeated, or just between these two. If it's always the same for a particular response/file, I would add a `sharedData` field next to `boxesDetail`.  If it's always the same for the program (and you think it will stay that way), you could use some kind of constant or resource file.

Comment: There's even a couple of free tools in the app store if you need offline access to JSON validation... I use `JSON Validator`

Answer (score 1):

Just as JeremyP says, you should use a JSON Parser to check your JSON. I also fully recommend [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) for checking JSON.

As far as an easy tutorial for CoreData I would recommend [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started). It's updated for iOS 5 so perhaps having an updated tutorial will help you understand. I haven't done the updated tutorial, but I'm pretty sure that's the one I looked at pre-iOS 5 when I was learning about CoreData.

After having a look at the CoreData tutorial and getting your head around it and understanding it, I would write a helper function as a category on your Box.

Something along the lines of

```
+ (id)boxWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
{
    Box *box = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Box" 
                                             inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    box.codeArticle    = [dict objectForKey:@"codeArticle"];
    box.nameBox        = [dict objectForKey:@"nameBox"];
    box.texteMarketing = [dict objectForKey:@"texteMarketing"];
    box.descriptionBox = [dict objectForKey:@"descriptionBox"];
    box.nbActivities   = [dict objectForKey:@"nbActivities"];
    box.kindBox        = [dict objectForKey:@"boxKind"];
    box.typeBox        = [dict objectForKey:@"boxType"];
    box.priceBox       = [dict objectForKey:@"priceBox"];
    box.dlu            = [dict objectForKey:@"dlu"];
    box.note           = [dict objectForKey:@"note"];

    return box;
}
```

The reason to put this code in a category and in a separate file to the Box.m and Box.h files that Xcode generate is so that if you ever edit the Box entity in CoreData and have to generate a new file, it won't overwrite this category file with your helper function.

I hope this helps.